# Can't dereference scalar in Perl

Tags: perl, reference, scalar

Can anyone tell me why this prints `REF(*)` instead of `0`?

```
$a = 0;
$a = \$a;
print $$a . "\n";
```

Comment: See also, `$$$a`, `$$$$a`, `$$$$$a`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Erm, because `$a` doesn't contain 0 any more, but instead a reference to itself. You overwrote it in the second line!

If you want to set `$a` to a reference to `$a`'s *original value* then you can write

```
$a = \"$a"
```

which works by using an *expression* that happens to evaluate to the value of `$a`, and taking a reference to that. This will fail if `$a` starts out as something other than a simple string or number, such as a reference or any value which changes when it is stringified. Then you could write an identity function such as

```
sub i { shift }
```

and use

```
$a = \i($a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your last assignment makes `$a` to reference to itself, so dereferencing it makes sense as chasing own tail in circular manner,

```
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

$a = 0;
$a = \$a;

print Dumper $a;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = \$VAR1;
```

You might want to make reference to a list of values which does what you want,

```
($a) = \map { $_ } $a;

print Dumper $a;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = \0;
```